# C# linq groupby returns incorrect groups

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to understand how linq works.
i wrote a test app and it is not working the way i expect it to.
from the following code, i am expecting to see items "test1" and "test4" grouped together, but i am not getting that. instead I am getting back 4 separate groups. meaning one of the items are getting grouped together.
can someone explain what i am doing wrong?
Thanks.

```
public class linqtest
{   public int x1;
    public int x2;
    public string x3;

    public linqtest(int a, int b, string c)
    {
        x1 = a;
        x2 = b;
        x3 = c;

    }

    public bool Equals(linqtest other)
    {

        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        return x1 == other.x1 &&
                x2 == other.x2;

    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(linqtest)) return false;
        return Equals((linqtest)obj);
    }
}
linqtest tc14 = new linqtest(1, 4, "test1");
inqtest tc15 = new linqtest(3, 5, "test2");
linqtest tc16 = new linqtest(3, 6, "test3");
linqtest tc16a = new linqtest(1, 4, "test4");

List<linqtest> tclistitems = new List<linqtest>();
tclistitems.Add(tc14);
tclistitems.Add(tc15);
tclistitems.Add(tc16);
tclistitems.Add(tc16a);

IEnumerable<IGrouping<linqtest, linqtest>> tcgroup = tclistitems.GroupBy(c => c);
```

why does tcgroup contain 4 groups? i was expecting 3 groups.

Comment: Did you check for warnings before posting? I'd expect the compiler to at least warn you that you're not overriding GetHashCode.

Comment: thanks. no i did not get a warning that i should override GetHashCode.

Comment: What are you using to compile? I've just compiled your *exact* code and received: "Test.cs(7,14): warning CS0659: 'linqtest' overrides Object.Equals(object o) but does not override Object.GetHashCode()". I would try to fix this before anything else - it's important that you can see warnings.

Comment: i am using visual studio 2008. maybe it is because i am using an older version?? I do get warnings for other stuff

Answer (score 6):

The error happens because you override `Equals` without overriding `GetHashCode`. These two must be overriden together, otherwise `GroupBy` will not work.

Add this code to your class to fix the issue:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    // You are ignoring x3 for equality, so hash code must ignore it too
    return 31*x1+x2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to override `Equal` method, just take advantage of anonymous class since anonymous class compares based on properties like `struct`:

```
tcgroup = tclistitems.GroupBy(c => new { c.x1, c.x2 });
```

Comment: But it creates unnecessary objects in memory.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: yes, of course, but performance I think is trivial in this case, this code is simpler and more readable.

Comment: @Cuong_Le: But there is already the custom class, so there's almost no overhead in adding `GetHashCode`. It's also short and readable and encapsulated. I just wanted to mention it since most people don't know that an anonymous type creates something new.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: thanks for your point :), take this answer, like another option for OP